# Beautify all files before/after a pull request on github

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github, travis-ci

Is there a way so that whenever a pull request is created on github, a new pull request is automatically created after running some npm command (ex. npm run beautify) so that I don't have to worry about the beautification process.

If any such thing can be done which automatically adds a commit to the current pull request which beautifies all the files, even that works fine.

I am ok with using any free third party softwares (Greenkeeper, travis or whatever)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a git hook both on server and local or set up local filters (smudge/clean) to beautify your code before it even being committed to the repo.

### ***`Git hooks`***

Read the [official docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) for a full reference.

---

### ***`Smudge / clean`***

Read all about it and to set it up here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

> **It turns out that you can write your own filters** for doing substitutions in files on **commit/checkout**.
>
> These are called `clean` and `smudge` filters.
>
> In the `.gitattributes` file, you can set a filter for particular paths and then set up scripts that will process files just before they’re checked out (“smudge”, see Figure below) and just before they’re staged (“clean”, see Figure 8-3).
>
> These filters can be set to do all sorts of fun things.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, I really learned a lot of new things and successfully achieved what I wanted :-)